What is the best analysis method to explore the correlation between performance and attention across multiple conditions in a within-subjects design?
I would appreciate any input on determining the most appropriate analysis for my data. My study involves participants completing two tasks:
Task 1: Participants evaluated their performance under three different conditions (choosing the correct word labels in happiness, sadness, and anger). The data consist of discrete numbers representing the number of correct labels chosen in each condition.
Task 2: Participants’ attention was assessed under two conditions, focusing on reaction time and response accuracy.
I aim to explore the correlation between the conditions in Task 1 and those in Task 2, but I am struggling with how to account for within-subject variability in my analysis. Each participant has five measurement points across the two tasks, and I believe that Pearson/Spearman correlations may not be the most suitable techniques for this data.
A colleague suggested using the glmer function in R, but I am uncertain about how to proceed or whether this is the best approach. Any advice on appropriate statistical methods or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance for your help.

I am not exactly sure what your scientific question is but you might possibly be looking for canonical correlation or for principal component analysis.

What is your research question?

This statement needs to be fleshed out for us to be able to help you - " I aim to explore the correlation between the conditions in Task 1 and those in Task 2."
